# Can't Obtain Panoramas From Newer Minecraft Versions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

Exactly as the title says. I've dug into the actual jar files and found that in the gui/title/backgrounds folder, the panoramas for 1.14+ are stuck on the 1.13 Update Aquatic one. It's strange since I can clearly see the new panoramas when loading the game. I tried deleting the new versions to force the game to re-download them to see if that would help, but still receive the same problem.

Comment: To make this clearer: The "panorama" is the background in the main menu, located in `assets/minecraft/textures/gui/title/background` in resource packs, including the default inside .jar files.

Comment: For me all of those files are 1×1 grey pixels. Weird. I checked my 13 installed versions and it's all the same. `panorama_overview.png` is either a 1×1 transparent pixel or a regular overlay how it's supposed to look.